# Как сделать в row bootstrap кнопки и поля ввода на одном уровне?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, разметка

***С помощью такой вот разметки я пытаюсь сделать кнопки и поля ввода на одном уровне (используется `angular 2`, но к проблеме он никакого отношения не имеет):***

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button (click)="__save()" class="btn btn-success">Сохранить шаблон</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button (click)="__remove()" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить шаблон</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="statusTemplateInput">Изменить статус</label>
            <ng-select id="statusTemplateInput"
                       [items]="statuses"
                       [active]="[{id: _template.status, text: _template.status}]">
            </ng-select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="titleInputName">Название шаблона</label>
            <input type="text" class="input input-md form-control" [(ngModel)]="_template.title" id="titleInputName"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

***В итоге получается такое:***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке видно, что из-за описания полей ввода, сами поля скатились вниз и находятся не на том же уровне, что и кнопки. Можно ли это как-нибудь поправить ?

Comment: Не знаю насколько правильно, попробуйте `<div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top: 25px;">`

Comment: @MrFylypenko такой себе совет. @faoxis, во-первых, у Bootstrap 4 есть свои хелперы для отступов. Во-вторых, можно использовать пустой `label`. И оберните все в `.form-group`.